# does socket __exit__ close in python?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, exit

I want to know if the:

```
with open_the_socket() as s:
    use s
```

works as intended. I read on another question that it would work provided that the socket's **exit** function calls for a close. It was said that 2.7 didn't, but I'm using 3.4 and I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a snippet from *Python 3.4.0*'s *socket.py*:

```py
def __exit__(self, *args):
    if not self._closed:
        self.close()
```

So, it closes the socket (as opposed to *Python 2.7.10*, where there's no *__exit__* method for the *socket* object).

Check [[Python 3.4.Docs]: Data model - With Statement Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) for more details on context managers.

Sample test code:

> ```
> >>>
> >>> import socket
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> s = None
> >>>
> >>> with socket.create_connection(("www.example.com", 80)) as s:
> ...     print(s._closed)
> ...
> False
> >>>
> >>> print(s._closed)
> True
> ```

On *Python 2*, closing the socket could be forced (thanks @glglgl for the tip) using [[Python 2.Docs]: contextlib.closing(thing)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```py
with contextlib.closing(open_the_socket()) as s:
    print(s)
    #use s
```

Comment: To extend on this: When there is no `__exit__` method, the OP can easily use `with contextlib.closing(open_the_socket()) as s:`.